# Build failed.Step 2: Build and initialize the new recipe. Initialize the system

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to install Spartacus for SAP Commerce 2005 following the guide:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/

At Step 2-3 (Initialize the system using the following command) I've got an error:

```
    [testClassesScanner] Found 12 ordercalculation testclasses in 7.191 ms                                                                                                      
    [touch] Creating C:\CX2005\hybris\temp\hybris\touch\ordercalculation_testsrctouch                                                                                       
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\outboundservices                                                                                
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\outboundservices                                                                                
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\outboundservices\classes                                                                             
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\odata2services                                                                                  
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\odata2services                                                                                  
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\odata2services\classes                                                                               
   [yjavac] Compiling 73 source files to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\outboundservices\classes                                                             
   [yjavac] Compiling 396 source files to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\odata2services\classes                                                              
    [touch] Creating C:\CX2005\hybris\temp\hybris\touch\outboundservices_srctouch                                                                                           
  [groovyc] Compiling 26 source files to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\outboundservices\classes                                                             
    [touch] Creating C:\CX2005\hybris\temp\hybris\touch\odata2services_srctouch                                                                                             
  [groovyc] Compiling 150 source files to C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integration-apis\odata2services\classes                                                              
[testClassesScanner] Found 218 odata2services testclasses in 16.72 ms                                                                                                       
    [touch] Creating C:\CX2005\hybris\temp\hybris\touch\odata2services_testsrctouch                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                            
BUILD FAILED                                                                                                                                                                
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                                         
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:75: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                       
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:116: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                      
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:42: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                            
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:44: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                            
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                      
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:340: The following error occurred while executing this line:                                                      
C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\platform\groovynature\buildcallbacks.xml:33: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\modules\integrati
n-apis\outboundservices\testsrc\de\hybris\platform\outboundservices\client\RestTemplateFactoryIntegrationTest.groovy' null                                                  
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:980)                                                                         
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:651)                                                                           
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:600)                                                                                    
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:583)                                                                                    
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:75)                                                                                 
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:243)                                                                          
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.runCompiler(Groovyc.java:1206)                                                                                                   
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:1258)                                                                                                       
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:853)
```

The last part of the log:

```
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:976)
        ... 102 more

Total time: 10 minutes 32 seconds

> Task :recipes:cx-for-spa:buildSystem FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\CX2005\installer\recipes\cx-for-spa\build.gradle' line: 594

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':recipes:cx-for-spa:buildSystem'.
> external process returned non-zero exit code, command: [cmd, /c, set "ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" & set "PLATFORM_HOME=C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform" & set "ANT_HOME=C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant" & set "PATH=C:\CX2005\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant\bin;%PATH%" & ant clean all]
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Regards,
Jegors

Answer (score 1):

Commenting out below line in installer/customconfig/custom.properties resolved the issue.
#build.parallel=true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, maybe you should install Grunt and that is all.
I hope to be resolved your answer
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing NodeJS path environment variable in windows.

Reffer [this](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12762438/getting-this-build-error-while-initializing-sap-hy.html) discussion from **answers.sap.com**, will help.