# SAP Commerce Cloud 2105 Installation on MAC OS Build Error: The command failed with exit code 127

Tags: failed-installation, build-error, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to setup SAP Commerce Cloud v2105 project in my MAC OS machine for Spartacus development.
I'm using this guide: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2105/

So far I have installed the pre-requisites:
JDK 11 => soon changed it to SAP Machine JDK 11 based on this: [SAP Commerce Cloud with Spartacus installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751645/sap-commerce-cloud-with-spartacus-installation-error)
NodeJS version 12
Angular CLI version 10
Setup JAVA_HOME

Everything is going well until i got this error while running the command:
`./install.sh -r cx-for-spa initialize`

**Error**

```
> Task :recipes:cx-for-spa:buildSystem FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/installer/recipes/cx-for-spa/build.gradle' line: 604

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':recipes:cx-for-spa:buildSystem'.
> external process returned non-zero exit code, command: [sh, -c, export PLATFORM_HOME="/Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/platform" && export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" && export ANT_HOME="/Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/platform/apache-ant" && chmod +x "/Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/platform/apache-ant/bin/ant" &&  export PATH="$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH" &&  ant clean all]
```

**Stacktrace**

```
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] Running "pnpm install" in /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] The command failed:
 [exec]  /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm install --no-prefer-frozen-lockfile --strict-peer-dependencies
 [exec] ERROR: Error: The command failed with exit code 127
 [exec] 
 [exec] Trying again (attempt #2)...
 [exec] 
 [exec] Deleting the "node_modules" folder
 [exec] 
 [exec] The command failed:
 [exec]  /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm install --no-prefer-frozen-lockfile --strict-peer-dependencies
 [exec] ERROR: Error: The command failed with exit code 127
 [exec] 
 [exec] Trying again (attempt #3)...
 [exec] 
 [exec] Deleting the "node_modules" folder
 [exec] 
 [exec] The command failed:
 [exec]  /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm install --no-prefer-frozen-lockfile --strict-peer-dependencies
 [exec] ERROR: Error: The command failed with exit code 127
 [exec] 
 [exec] /bin/sh: /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm: No such file or directory
 [exec] /bin/sh: /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm: No such file or directory
 [exec] /bin/sh: /Users/programmer/Documents/projects/commercloud/hybris/bin/modules/smartedit/smartedittools/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm: No such file or directory
 [exec] Giving up after 3 attempts
 [exec] 
 [exec] 
 [exec] ERROR: The command failed with exit code 127
 [exec]
```

**What I tried to far**

Solution #1 - removed NodeJS and NPM and redid everything
Reference: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12762725/hybris-63-sapaomsomb2bb2c-ant-clean-all-error.html?childToView=12794099 - **DIDN'T WORK**

Solution #2 - manually removed node_modules on the pnpm directory, but only shortcut found and no node_modules folder found

Solution #3 - reinstalled Angular CLI - **DIDN'T WORK**

Solution #4 - This solution => [SAP Commerce Cloud with Spartacus installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751645/sap-commerce-cloud-with-spartacus-installation-error) - **DIDN'T WORK**

Solution #5 - commented out all extensions related to *smartedit* on the **build.gradle** file - **DIDN'T WORK**

Solution #6 - Uninstalled Visual Studio code as it might cause conflict - **DIDN'T WORK**

Solution #7 - Commented the build parallel flag
Reference: [Build failed.Step 2: Build and initialize the new recipe. Initialize the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396928/build-failed-step-2-build-and-initialize-the-new-recipe-initialize-the-system) - **DIDN'T WORK**

Just asking here, there might be people out there who experienced the same issues.

Comment: what is your npm version? run `npm -v`  in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change the pnpm version to 5.18.10 on "bin\modules\smartedit\smartedittools\common\config\rush.tpl.json";
Delete .pnpm-store under your Windows $HOME;
Trigger commerce build

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your setup is that you are missing some pre-reqs for SmartEdit extensions.
Try running `ant npminstall` to enable full build
(https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/6d55d5fba206425b9acecda9f2311483.html?version=1905&locale=en-US)

But, I suggest you to not include smartedit extensions in local env.

I am using, also, a SAP Commerce 2105 with Spartacus, and I am injecting Smartedit extensions only at cloud envs.

I think SmartEdit is really heavy to include at local envs.